# Access NTFS partitions without providing root password?

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, ntfs

I have Ubuntu and Windows Vista installed on the same disk, different partitions.

I can access the Windows data, but each (first) time I access the NTFS partition, the system asks me for root password.

Can I somehow allow my user to mount/access those partitions automatically?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your /etc/fstab?  This may be as simple as providing the "user" option in your NTFS entry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- If you feel that you dont want to enter password on mounting and unmounting then one way is to edit sudoers file.

  ```
  sudo visudo
  ```
- Add the following two lines at the end of your file.

  ```
  username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/mount      
  username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/umount
  ```

  [image]
- If you want to automount your drives at startup then install [**pysdm** [image: Install pysdm]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pysdm)

  [image]