# User Permissions

Tags: permissions, scripts

Is there any way with which, using shell scripts, I can execute a program as another user, in a uniquely(randomly) named directory, where the user has rwx access to all the files in that directory, but cannot change anything outside it.

i.e. When a program is executed using this script in a folder, it can only access files inside the folder and cannot change any system settings or navigate outside this folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rbash` (or `bash -r`): it is a restricted version of `bash` that imposes some limitations to the user with respect to full bash. From `rbash` man page:

> It behaves identically to bash with the exception that the following are disallowed or not performed:
>
> ```
>    o      changing directories with cd
>    o      setting or unsetting the values of SHELL, PATH, ENV, or BASH_ENV
>    o      specifying command names containing /
>    o      specifying a file name containing a / as an argument to the . builtin command
>    o      Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the -p option to the hash builtin command
>    o      importing function definitions from the shell environment at startup
>    o      parsing the value of SHELLOPTS from the shell environment at startup
>    o      redirecting output using the >, >|, <>, >&, &>, and >> redirection operators
>    o      using the exec builtin command to replace the shell with another command
>    o      adding or deleting builtin commands with the -f and -d options to the enable builtin command
>    o      Using the enable builtin command to enable disabled shell builtins
>    o      specifying the -p option to the command builtin command
>    o      turning off restricted mode with set +r or set +o restricted.
> ```

To use `rbash` trasparently, start your script with `#!/bin/rbash`.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo -u USERNAME
```

EDIT:
To use this command without entering password, use:

```
echo PASSWORD | sudo -u USERNAME COMMAND
```

Replace PASSWORD with the password of USERNAME.
Replace USERNAME with the username.
Replace COMMAND with the command you want to execute.

For example:

```
echo password123 | sudo -u daniel cp ./file ./dir/filecopied
```

I hope this helped you,
Daniel

Comment: You'd better run `sudo visudo` to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file and add a NOPASSWD for the command instead of writing the password in the script.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Make it a separate answer.

Comment: @Adam Byrtek: the question needs additional details. In the current form, the answer would be "no, it is not possible". For usage instructions on NOPASSWD and visudo, see [this question with instructions on running mount as root without a password](http://askubuntu.com/q/19611/6969). Note that the script will be run as root.

Comment: On a side note. By default, sudo does not read the password from stdin, it reads it directly from the terminal, so `echo PASSWORD | sudo -u USERNAME COMMAND` will not work. Just run the script as root. With the default sudoers, root can run commands as any user without requiring a password.