# can't mount ntfs partition without root access 

Tags: mount, root, ntfs

whenever try to mount ntfs partition it says

> Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
>   Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external
>   FUSE library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with
>   integrated FUSE support and make it setuid root. Please see more
>   information at http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged
>   I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/19612/39372) answer but it wont work

[image]

my etc/fstab file

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                       /proc        proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid              0  0  
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=ed9e007f-da86-4436-993a-8670ebf45939  /            ext4  errors=remount-ro                0  1  
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=956e15af-d650-42ac-a5f6-89955abaacde  none         swap  sw                               0  0  
/dev/sda1                                  /media/sda1  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,ro,umask=000,user  0  0
```

Comment: If you're running out of the box Ubuntu, I've never seen this happen.

Comment: Can u check my updated answer and verify it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the contents of /etc/fstab file ?

As its a very important file, backup it first.

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
```

Instead of doing it on command line, do it using GUI tools please check this

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/how-to-mount-partitions-automatically.html

Note: Its a very important file. Please double check before doing any changes.

Update : Looks like you are not able to change settings with pysdm due to some bug in it - "No matter what I do with pysdm - Mount file system in read-only mode, still remains checked."

This can be fixed by manually editing /etc/fstab file . Changed

```
/dev/sda1                                  /media/sda1  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,ro,umask=000,user  0  0
```

to

```
/dev/sda1                                  /media/sda1  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,rw,umask=000,user  0  0
```

or even

```
/dev/sda1                                  /media/sda1  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,umask=000,user  0  0
```

and rebooted the system.

Comment: question updated

Comment: answer updated as well.

Comment: lol pysdm is the reason for this error

Comment: pysdm wont work :(

Comment: Have you done these settings - make sure the "Mount file system in read-only mode" is unchecked (this is automatically checked for NTFS partitions),

- check the "Allow any user to mount the file system" box,

- check the "Allow a user to mount and unmount the filesystem" box,

Comment: yeah i unchecked

Comment: And your settings are same as this ? - http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Lhl6pLGc6os/TrRXhwsYQ5I/AAAAAAAAGkQ/jQ4tMOfARkA/s2000/storage-device-manager_3.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3047/discussion-between-tachyons-and-mac)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem caused by pysdm.

I just deleted entries made by pysdm in fstab, as I didn't want NTFS partition to automount, I just wanted to be able to mount it by clicking in Nautilus. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good answer to the NTFS-3g problem here.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661757

Comment: Can you include the relevant parts of the solution here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got a similar problem.

In my case (Ubuntu 12.04, using gparted and pysdm) I got a loading problem at start up, `sdb2 was not able to mount at media/partitionName` , where `partitionName` was the folder I set up with `pysdm`. In my case I was able to use and automount at start up before, and suddenly this problem started.

Then I was not able to mount it manually either, and I got the message `Unable to mount....` (see figure in the first question above). I found that the problem was generated by windows hibernation. After I restarted from windows and turn it off the whole problem disappeared. I was able to see that the problem was hibernation when I tried to mount by hand:

`sudo mount -t /dev/sdb2 /media/partitonName`

Hope this could help some one.

Answer (score 0):

My NTFS mounts have always been fine until I try to get them to mount at boot - then its one drama after another. I had the same prob with pysdm as the OP. This suggestion from mac (above) appears to have fixed it -

```
/dev/sda1                                  /media/sda1  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,rw,umask=000,user
```

I commented out the old entry in fstab generated by pysdm though, it looks like this -

```
/dev/sda5                                  /media/data       ntfs  
# nls=iso8859-1,rw,group=users,users,umask=000,gid=users,user,owner,uid=fnord  0  0  
nls=iso8859-1,rw,umask=000,user  0  0
```

It works on reboot, BUT - there is a mount error when it's booting, with a "ignore or repair". I ignore, it boots and everything is perfect.

EDIT - Well, that was enthusiastic moderation. Unaware hardware shop items can cause flagging... My question again - I am hesitant to do other changes to fstab. I was wondering if my change shown above is the cause of the bootup mount error warning?